# Two equal tables (different column numbers) have different number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

AWS Redshift DB

I have two tables A and B

```
select col1, col2 from A
except
select col1, col2 from B
```

returns empty, the same

```
select col1, col2 from B
except
select col1, col2 from A
```

returns empty

but

```
select count(*) from A
```

returns for example 100, but

```
select count(*) from B
```

returns 200

how can that be ?

Comment: you should use `EXCEPT ALL` instead of `EXCEPT`, you can workaround it with `row_number()` over all columns

Answer (score 2):

Because each tables distinct data set is contained in the other. A different count means that you have duplicate rows. This might make it clearer.

```
Distinct(A) is a subset of B
Distinct(B) is a subset of A
```